# Gmail attachment to google drive folder using python and google api

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-api, gmail-api

Planning to create an python script that can automatically connect the gmail api and gdrive api to download the attachment of the specific email everytime the script executed, is it possible to do it on a linux server without GUI?

Comment: You mean "Is it possible to write a script on a linux server without GUI"?

Comment: Please do not ask **is it possible** type of questions. Instead, show your work and the specific problem you have with your software/program. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: apologize for the confusion, while I'm searching for the idea on how to connect my server to gmail api all of the sources I've search it requires an GUI to verify it using browser that automatically pops up after running the script and connect the server to gmail... my question how can I connect my linux server without GUI to gmail api using python script? inaddition, I already created an python script from my previous project using gsheet API, right now I exploring the gmail api

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand my issue...